# Modular arithmetic for arbitrary number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

The problem describes as:

> When the even integer $n$ is divided by $7$，the remainder is $3$. What's is
>   The remainder when $n$ is divided by $14$.

My simple solution is:

> $n=7x+3$ where $x$ is odd, so, we can define $x = 2m+1$, then $n = 7(2m+1) + 3 = 14m + 7 +3= 14m + 10$. So reminder is: $10$

As I am learning the mod system and was trying to solve this problem with modulo arithmetic. But got stuck with "how to think this prob in modulo system" ie. if $$n \equiv 3 \pmod{7} $$ then $$n \equiv \ ? \pmod {14} $$

Any help regarding solving steps and learning reference would be appreciated.

Comment: "how to think this prob in modulo system" well it depends of the meaning of those words, but IMHO I think you did it nicely that way indeed. You converted a problem in $\pmod{7}$ to a problem in $\pmod{14}$. Maybe is just a question of formatting your answer as a "modulo system problem": $x = 2m+1$, then $n = 7(2m+1) + 3 \pmod{14} \equiv 14m + 7 +3 \pmod{14} \equiv  14m + 10 \pmod {14} \equiv 14m \pmod{14} + 10 \pmod {14} \equiv 10 \pmod{14}$.

Comment: Edited the question a bit for better understandability of my points that is, I was thinking the format: if n mod 7 = 3 then n mod 14 = ?. That's how I was thinking. Thanks for replying!

Comment: ok I have added a solution going backwards... I think that you meant that possibility. But the way you did it is easier and indeed my solution is based on your substitutions (but backwards, it is kind of tricky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I said in the comments I think is fine the way you did it. I would suggest you to use "congruent to" instead of "equal to" as in my comment from the beginning, or add it at the end of the conversions you did as a last step.
>
> Said that, maybe your question is more related with this point: **how you could make a solution starting backwards?** from $14m+r$.

Let us start with:

$$n=14m+r$$

Then, let us suppose three possibilities:

1. $r \lt 7$
2. $r = 7$
3. $7 \lt r \lt 14$ so we can define $r=7+r'$, where $r' \lt 7$

---

- For the first case:

$$n=14m+r \pmod{7} \equiv 2\cdot 7m\pmod{7} + r \pmod{7} \equiv 0+r \equiv 3$$

Thus:

$$r=3$$

But that is not possible because it means that $n = 14m + 3$, but $14m+3$ **is not even, and we know that $n$ is even**, so that solution is not possible.

- For the second case:

$$n=14m+7 \pmod{7} \equiv 2\cdot 7\pmod{7} + 7 \pmod{7} \equiv 0 \equiv 3$$

So it is impossible for the residue to be $r=7$ because $14m+7 \not \equiv 3 \pmod {7}$, **the residue does not comply the premise**, being $\equiv {3} \pmod{7}$, it is indeed $\equiv {0} \pmod {7}$.

- For the third case:

$$n=14m+r \pmod{7} \equiv 2\cdot 7\pmod{7} + 7 + r' \pmod{7} \equiv 0+0+r' \equiv 3$$

> Thus finally the unique remaining valid option is $7 \lt r = 10 \lt 14$:
>
> $$r'=3, r=7+r'=7+3=10$$